# How to simulate mobile app slide view with CSS and AngularJS properly?

Tags: css, angularjs

Here is what I've done after researching and changing:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kylex/FV36z/3/)

```
.cube {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}

.container1 {
    display: inline;
}

.container2 {
    display: inline;
}

.animate-enter, 
.animate-leave { 
    -webkit-transition: 1s all ;
    -moz-transition: 1s all ;
    -o-transition: 1s all ;
    transition: 1s all ;
    position: relative;
}

.animate-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.animate-leave {
    left: 0;
    display: inline;
}
.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

1.But there is still a problem, the two divs are not in line.
I tried to put display:inline to the .cube and .container class, doesn't help.
*What I want is to have page2 appear right next to page1 and they both slide together, just like mobile sliding views. And I don't want to combine those views together as an entire block like most banners do.

2.Now I have only set the "enter" and "leave" animation sliding to the left. How can I provide another "enter" and "leave" animation within the .cube div?
E.g. Page1 slides to the left to leave, page2 slides from the right to enter.
I also want to provide another button which will have page3 slide to the right to leave, and page1 slide in from the right to enter. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the second problem. Why do you think that animations cannot be combined? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am an angularjs noob, so please bear with me. The code here "ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'" sets the enter and leave animation of the element inside the .cube div. So whenever an element is leaving, it triggers the "leave" animation, which is set to "slide to left". Now I want to provide another button to slide the element to the right as "leave" animation. How can I do that? -Please see the update of the fiddle link. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Adding floats for .container1, .container2 solves first problem.

Comment: Now the .cube div expand to double size when the animation is on, and the new page only reaches to the right half of the div. Not a perfect solution though...

Answer (score 0):

1. put position:absolute into .animate-enter and position:relative into .animate-leave solves the first problem.

and also set the containers with float. -@eRIZ

1. set the animation as a variable and pass a boolean to javascript to set the animation.